# Dependent Picklist Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, dependent-picklist

I select the country in the frist field than should show the second field the state, that works fine. But If I select the state I want to select the city in the third field. It doesn't work.

```
<apex:page controller="ctlDepPickLst">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
               <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Country"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>        
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>                
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!country}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!countries}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a"/>
                </apex:selectList>                
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="State"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!state}" id="a">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!states}"/>
                    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" reRender="b"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>  
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!city}" id="b">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!city}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>                                     
        </apex:pageBlockSection>        
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Class :**

```
public class ctlDepPickLst {
public String country {get;set;}
public String state {get;set;}
public String city {get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getCountries()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- Select ---'));        
    options.add(new SelectOption('US','United States'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('IN','India'));
    return options;
} 

public List<SelectOption> getStates()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    if(country == 'US')
    {       
        options.add(new SelectOption('CO','Colorado'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('NE','Nevada'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('TE','Texas'));
    }
    else if(country == 'IN')
    {       
        options.add(new SelectOption('BI','Bihar'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('KE','Kerala'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('MA','Manipur'));
    }
    else
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- Select ---'));
    }      
    return options;
}       

public List<SelectOption> getCity()
{
    List<SelectOption> options2 = new List<SelectOption>();        
    if(state == 'CO')
    {
        options2.add(new SelectOption('BE','CO1'));
        options2.add(new SelectOption('MU','CO2'));
    }
    else
    {
        options2.add(new SelectOption('MI','test1'));
        options2.add(new SelectOption('AB','test2'));        
    }
    return options2;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

believe its due to the variable and method name conflict on city..

you have a string variable called **city**

and you have a method called **getCity** to return the SelectOption list

to be consistent, if you change ur method name to getCities and use that in your VF page for city list, it should work.

Page :

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!cities}"/>
```

Controller :

```
public List<SelectOption> getCities()
{
    List<SelectOption> options2 = new List<SelectOption>();        
    if(state == 'CO')
    {
        options2.add(new SelectOption('BE','CO1'));
        options2.add(new SelectOption('MU','CO2'));
    }
    else
    {
        options2.add(new SelectOption('MI','test1'));
        options2.add(new SelectOption('AB','test2'));        
    }
    return options2;
}
```